# Power spectral bandwidth interpretation

Tags: rf

I'm developing a LoRa solution that I want to check is compliant with radio spectrum laws in Australia. The radio will transmit at 915Mhz at 22dBm (158mW) with a channel bandwidth of 500Khz, and won't be setup for channel hopping.

The legislation says (for digital modulation transmitters as its not channel hopping):

```
915–928 1 W The radiated peak power spectral density in any 3 kHz must not exceed 
25 mW per 3 kHz
```

My interpretation of this is that as the 22dBm power is spread across 500Khz, then looking at the power in a 3K slice will have a much smaller proportion of the total power (3/500) assuming the power distribution is linear across the bandwidth. Even if the power distribution isn't linear I should be well within the legislated limits.

Am I reading this right?

Comment: Just because the channel BW is 500KHz, the power spectral density need not be uniform across that 500KHz. Different data bitstreams will affect the local (3KHz wide) power.

Comment: I understand its likely not a linear spread, my question was about my assumption that if taking a 3K slice the power in the 3K slice is much smaller than the 22dBm at 500Khz? So unless I have really poor linearity I should be well within legal limits.

Comment: At a glance )or two) yes, your interpretation seems reasonable. I wouldn't rely on my opinion, but I'm swayed by yours :-).